# How do I make a list with the same name as a dictionary key?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

I have a dictionary, containing several hundred entries, of format:

```
>>>dict
{'1620': 'aaaaaa'}
```

I would like to make new empty lists named '1620', etc. I have tried variations of the following but it doesn't recognize eachkey as a variable to be used when creating the list. Instead, it names the list literally "eachkey" and my key, in this example '1620', is not connected to the new list.

```
>>>for eachkey in dict.keys():
>>>    eachkey=[]
>>>
>>>eachkey
[]
>>>'1620'
1620
```

Edited to add:
Maybe I could make the list at the same time as I make the dictionary? Slip it in here below? The str(eachfile[-4:]) is what I want the list named.

```
files=open(sys.argv[1])
dict={}
for eachfile in files:
    value=open(eachfile)
    key=str(eachfile[-4:])
    dict[key]=value
eachfile.close()
```

Edit: it would be fine for me to add letters along w/ the numbers if that's what it needs.

Comment: Please consider very seriously whether you actually want to do this. (Let me put it differently: I am about 99.9% confident that it is a bad idea, even taking into account that you want to do it and that I don't know your reasons.)

Comment: Also, don't name your dictionary `dict` or you'll be in for some nasty surprises down the road.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan is correct. Perhaps you could explain why you're doing this so we can suggest a better way to achieve your goal?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to change the integer literal `1620` so that it gives you an object other than the integer 1620. Similarly I don't think you can change the string literal `'1620'` to give you a list instead of a string.

You could do it if you prefix the variable names with some letters to make them valid names. For example you could use `my1620` instead of `1620`. I wouldn't advise doing this, but it's possible:

```
>>> d = {'1620': 'aaaaaa'}
>>> for k,v in d.items():
...     locals()['my'+k] = []
>>> my1620
'aaaaaa'
```

Comment: I don't want the list to contain the value. I want it empty so I can put other data in it later.

Comment: @user1539097: Umm... so assign an empty list instead?

Comment: >>> for k in dict.items():
    ...     locals()["my"+k]=[]
    ... 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
    TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects

Comment: If you don't know why that error happens or how to fix it, you probably shouldn't be doing something as evil as creating local names dynamically from a dictionary. Try to find a different way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

With a dict like this:

```
d1 = {'foo':'bar', '1621':'hello'}
```

Try doing this:

```
d2 = dict((k,list()) for k in d1.keys())
```

Now d2 is:

```
{'1621': [], 'foo': []}
```

And you can reference your lists list so:

```
d2['1621'].append(20)
d2['foo'].append(5)
d2['foo'].append('zig')
```

Which makes d2:

```
{'1621': [20], 'foo': [5, 'zig']}
```

As Gareth said, it's VERY unlikely you really want to do what you're asking to do.  This is probably better.